# How to run Timeshift from command line

Tags: command-line, timeshift

I'm struggling a bit with running Timeshift from command line. My disk structure look like this:

```
sda                         8:0    0   1.8T  0 disk
├─sda1                      8:1    0   512M  0 part /boot/efi
├─sda2                      8:2    0     1G  0 part /run/timeshift/backup
└─sda3                      8:3    0   1.8T  0 part
  └─ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv 253:0    0   100G  0 lvm  /
sdb                         8:16   0 232.9G  0 disk
└─sdb1                      8:17   0 232.9G  0 part /run/timeshift/backup
```

So, I would like to create a backup on the sdb1 disk, using:

```
sudo timeshift --create --comments "Test" --tags D --snapshot-device /dev/sdb1
```

gives me the following:

```
Mounted '/dev/sdb1' at '/run/timeshift/backup'
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Creating new snapshot...(RSYNC)
Saving to device: /dev/sdb1, mounted at path: /run/timeshift/backup
Linking from snapshot: 2022-02-17_19-34-54
Synching files with rsync...
Created control file: /run/timeshift/backup/timeshift/snapshots/2022-02-17_20-51-55/info.json
RSYNC Snapshot saved successfully (111s)
Tagged snapshot '2022-02-17_20-51-55': ondemand
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

However, when listing using timeshift --list, I get the following:

```
Mounted '/dev/sda2' at '/run/timeshift/backup'
Device : /dev/sda2
UUID   : acd80a0d-761d-441a-8e8a-b5cca5bf7ee9
Path   : /run/timeshift/backup
Mode   : RSYNC
Status : Not enough disk space (< 12.9 GB)
Select another device or free up some space

No snapshots found
```

Any suggestions on what I am doing wrong?

Tom

Comment: I suggest you unmount sda2 or just reboot and try again

Answer (score 0):

You should provide the snapshot-device like you did when you created the snapshot.
It comes like this:
timeshift --list --snapshot-device /dev/sdb1